# Return the number of lines required for paragraphs of text for a given width in Bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell

Given a width I am trying to calculate how many lines a block of text, that contains paragraphs (\n line endings), would take.

I cannot simply divide the number of characters by the width because the line endings create new lines early.  I cannot count the line endings only because some paragraphs will wrap.

I think that I need to loop through the paragraphs, dividing the characters by the width for each and adding the results together.

```
    count_lines() {
    TEXT="$(echo -e $1)"
    WIDTH=$2
    LINES=0
    for i in "${TEXT[@]}"
    do
    PAR=$(echo -e "$i" | wc -c)
    LINES=$LINES + (( $PAR / $WIDTH ))
    done
    RETURN $LINES
}
```

Reading the text as an array did not work.

Comment: Why do you use the `-e` argument to `echo`?

Comment: BTW, note that all-caps names are used for variables that modify or reflect behavior of OS-provided tools; applications should use lowercase names for their own variables to avoid conflicting, as described in the POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html (reading that spec, keep in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Comment: You might also want to run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, and follow the wiki links in the warnings it generates.

Comment: -e is to make the \n into line breaks in whiptail (which is why I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the lines).

Comment: `echo -e` is *supposed to* print `-e` on output -- [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) explicitly disallows implementations from supporting any options, with an exception only for `-n`. Bash supporting `echo -e` to do anything other than print `-e` is thus noncompliant with the spec, and *it doesn't always work*, because bash can be configured to be strictly spec-compliant (as it is with both `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags set; note that either or both of these can be set at either compile or runtime).

Comment: ...the POSIX-compliant alternative to bash's `echo -e "$i"`, guaranteed to work on all shells compliant with POSIX.2, is `printf '%b\n' "$i"`

Comment: ...anyhow, if you stored a string with literal newlines in your variable in the first place, you could just `echo "$i"` to print it with those newlines intact. Try it -- run the assignment in my answer, then `echo "$text"` with no `-e` anywhere.

Comment: (Something else I didn't point out earlier, by the way -- the `return` keyword is exactly that, in lowercase. However, it should only be used to set your command's exit status; if you want to return a value, echo it to stdout unless you're supporting a different calling convention, such as indirect assignment to a parameterized variable name).

Comment: ...looking at shellcheck's advice, it's actually less helpful than I'd hoped, so to throw in another note, the math would need to be something like `LINES=$(( LINES + (PAR / WIDTH) ))` to actually *be* math at all. Though since division rounds down to the nearest integer, you're not going to get accurate results that way.

Comment: ...similarly, `echo -e $1` is going to misbehave with a lot of strings unless you make it `echo -e "$1"`. If you have a whitespace-surrounded `*` inside your string, f/e, `echo $1` without quotes is going to replace it with a list of filenames; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count_lines() {
  fmt -w "$2" <<<"$1" | wc -l
}
```

- `fmt` is a longstanding (present as far back as Plan 9, and part of coreutils on GNU systems) UNIX tool which wraps text to a desired width.
- `<<<` is herestring syntax, a ksh and bash alternative to heredocs which allows their use without splitting a script into multiple lines.

---

Testing this:

```
text=$(cat <<'EOF'
This is a sample document with multiple paragraphs. This paragraph is the first one.

This is the second paragraph of the sample document.
EOF
)
count_lines "$text" 20
```

...returns output of `10`. That's correct, because the text wraps as follows (lines at the beginning added for readability):

```
 1 This is a
 2 sample document
 3 with multiple
 4 paragraphs. This
 5 paragraph is the
 6 first one.
 7 
 8 This is the second
 9 paragraph of the
10 sample document.
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome information, clearly I have a lot to learn.

Using this text I get a result of 5 for a width of 78, it should be 9.

```text="This is my first line of text, next two new lines.\n\nThird line of text, then two more new lines.\n\nFith Line then one more line, a curly brace, a new line, a hash, new line, close curly brace.\n{\n\"a9b31238d062ccb5f4b1eb6c3041d369cc014f5e6df38d2d303d791acd4302f2\": \"0\"\n}\nThis should be the Ninth line not including wrapping"```

Comment: `<<<` isn't changing your `\n` sequences to literal newlines. Of course, the best answer is to just specify them as literal newlines in the first place, and *not* to use `\n` sequences at all.

Comment: If I run `printf -v text %b "$text"` after your definition pasted above, and *then* run `count_lines "$text" 78` the result comes out as `8`, the lines broken as you can see at https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/6bca986a93bd9fc6a3b4275128f7ef76

Comment: BTW, if you want to write a multi-line literal in bash, one way to do that is `text=$'This is my first line of text, next two new lines.\n\nThird line of text, then two more new lines.\n\nFith Line then one more line, a curly brace, a new line, a hash, new line, close curly brace.\n{\n"a9b31238d062ccb5f4b1eb6c3041d369cc014f5e6df38d2d303d791acd4302f2": "0"\n}\nThis should be the Ninth line not including wrapping'` -- in `$''` quotes, `\n` is treated as a newline by the parser.

Comment: I'll go back to literal newlines.  Forget what problem I was trying to solve with the \n in the first place but with the tips and links you've given above I'm confident I'll find a more compliant way.

Comment: See https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings for more on the syntax I used above.